# Mysql exclusive left join on one to many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql

I have these two tables

```
facilities
+----+--------------------------------------+--------------+-------+------+------------+------------+
| id | name                                 | category     | image | cust | created_at | updated_at |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------------+-------+------+------------+------------+
|  1 | Bar                                  | hotel        |       |      | NULL       | NULL       |
|  2 | Minibar in alle Zimmer               | hotel        |       |      | NULL       | NULL       |
|  3 | Snack restaurant                     | hotel        |       |      | NULL       | NULL       |
|  4 | Grillroom                            | hotel        |       |      | NULL       | NULL       |
+----+--------------------------------------+--------------+-------+------+------------+------------+
```

table - 2

```
resortfacilities

+----+------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| id | f_id | created_at          | updated_at          | h_id |
+----+------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
| 42 | 4    | 2016-09-21 13:17:27 | 2016-09-21 13:17:27 |   35 |
| 59 | 1    | 2016-09-22 10:23:27 | 2016-09-22 10:23:27 |   38 |
| 60 | 4    | NULL                | NULL                |   38 |
+----+------+---------------------+---------------------+------+
```

And I have ran this following sql

```
SELECT
facilities.id,
facilities.`name`,
facilities.image,
resortfacilities.h_id
FROM
facilities
LEFT JOIN resortfacilities ON facilities.id = resortfacilities.f_id
WHERE
resortfacilities.f_id IS NULL AND
facilities.category = 'hotel' OR
resortfacilities.h_id <> 35
```

with the expectation of get getting the following result

```
+----+---------------------------+-------+------+
| id | name                      | image | h_id |
+----+---------------------------+-------+------+
|  4 | Grillroom                 |       |   38 |
|  2 | Minibar in alle Zimmer    |       | NULL |
|  3 | Snack restaurant          |       | NULL |
+----+---------------------------+-------+------+
```

with out the values that belongs to `h_id 35` but I end up with

```
+----+---------------------------+-------+------+
| id | name                      | image | h_id |
+----+---------------------------+-------+------+
|  1 | Bar                       |       |   38 |
|  4 | Grillroom                 |       |   38 |
|  2 | Minibar in alle Zimmer    |       | NULL |
|  3 | Snack restaurant          |       | NULL |
+----+---------------------------+-------+------+
```

May I know how to get the that result?

Comment: Try to place brackets for the expression **resortfacilities.f_id IS NULL AND
facilities.category = 'hotel' OR
resortfacilities.h_id <> 35**

Comment: it looks to me like your data isn't properly normalized. For example why does created_at occur in both tables?

Comment: Most probably `WHERE facilities.category = 'hotel' AND (
resortfacilities.f_id IS NULL 
 OR
resortfacilities.h_id <> 35)`

Answer (score 0):

use the below script (for getting the result as mentioned ).

```
SELECT
 f.id,
 f.`name`,
 f.image,
 r.h_id
FROM
facilities f
LEFT JOIN resortfacilities r ON f.id = f.f_id AND r.h_id <> 35
WHERE f.category = 'hotel'
```

Comment: Check your aliases